# How generate 2 different signed flavor builds with different keys inside Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two different release flavors in my Android project that use two different signing keys for production.

Currently in Android Studio, when you select the "Generate Signed APK..." option, you first have to specify the key store path and alias. If I pick one and try to build both releases, they both get built with the same signing key, even though I have specified my own `signingConfigs` section in my gradle file.

Is there any way to automatically build both release flavors in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from command line.
If you have local gradle:

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

If you have the wrapper:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

This will generate all apks related to release configurations and you will find them under: `$project_name/$module_name/build/outputs/apk/`

You can also do it from Gradle section in `Android Studio` choosing both `assemble${flavorName}Release` tasks:

[image: gradle tasks]

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I would rather do it from inside AS if possible.